# tkinter - get button name?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label

I'm trying to execute different code for each tkinter button - the names of which are not know until called from a list. gtk has get label (unfortunately I can't use gtk).

How might I implement similar with tkinter?

```
def click_one(newbuttonname):
        try:
                writethisdown = open("participantsmovedlog.txt", 'a')
        except:
                pass
        rotatee = newbuttonname
        thispersonwasrotated(rotatee)
        writethisdown.close()
```

.... and meanwhile within the makebutton function:

```
for someuser in listofusers:
            username = someuser
            newbuttonname = username 
            newbuttonname = Tkinter.Button(win, text = newbuttonname, command = lambda:click_one(username))
            newbuttonname.pack()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are almost there. You simply need to pass the name via lambda or functools.partial:

```
newbuttonname = username 
newbuttonname = Tkinter.Button(win, text = newbuttonname, 
    command = lambda name=username:click_one(name))
```

You can use this same technique to pass in the actual wodget, or any other data.

Comment: That's excellent! But I can't make Tkinter die not even with win.quit() or win.destroy() ?

Comment: @Donnied: I don't understand your comment. This question and answer has nothing to do with making a program die. If you're having problems, ask in another question and I'm sure someone will answer it.

Comment: Thanks Bryan - I had accepted your answer. It was just an aside really - I'd ask the question but it's been asked a dozen times - I suspect I'd get flamed - haven't you read threads x,y, & z? I'll go ahead and ask it...

Answer (score 12):

Bryan's answer may not exactly address the question, in particular, his solution works only if the button's text never changes after it has been created.

```
button.config('text')[-1]
```

returns the actual button's text.

Answer (score 0):

While you label the button, it should be in quotes:

```py
newbuttonname = tk.Button(win, text="NewButtonName")
```